# Need to apply CHECK constraint and length check on number in SQL

Tags: postgresql

I need to have a CHECK constraint on a datatype, which has to have a format of `010000` through `129999` with the zero preserved, but I don't know how to achieve this. Basically, as evident, it's a numeric month-year.

I have tried using `numeric(6,0)` and `integer`, but I don't know how to use a CHECK that preserves the leading zero.

I also don't know how I could achieve this more easily using `character varying(6)` and it's not preferred either, as I think it'll be harder to use in the application layer.

Any suggestions? I'm using Postgres.

Comment: If you want to store month and year I'd rather go for two integer columns.

Comment: I asked for that, but no can do.

Comment: How about `yyyymm` format (`201512, 201601`)?

Comment: Serious advise to store a date as a date, even of the day-part is irrelevant.

Comment: @wildplasser There's already a `date` field, but the month is for uniqueness. Take an example of salary: its record should be unique for the month, not just the date.

Comment: Salary: my first (date) example handles the once-per-month case very well. Just add a unique constraint *on top of* the domain/value/check constraint.

Comment: In the end, I went with @lad2025's option.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I ended up using a yyyymm format, as suggested by @lad2025.

Answer (score 1):

Three ways (there may be more):

```
        -- (1) use a date type for a date
CREATE TABLE mmyyyy
        ( id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , yyyymm01 DATE NOT NULL CHECK (date_trunc('month', yyyymm01) = yyyymm01)
        );

INSERT INTO mmyyyy(yyyymm01) VALUES
 ('1901-01-01') ,('0001-01-01') ,('2016-02-01') ;

INSERT INTO mmyyyy(yyyymm01) VALUES ('1901-13-01') ;  -- should fail
INSERT INTO mmyyyy(yyyymm01) VALUES ('2016-02-13') ; -- should fail

SELECT id, to_char(yyyymm01, 'mmyyyy') AS this FROM mmyyyy ;

        -- (2) use a char type and apply the check on the cast_to_int result
CREATE TABLE omg
        ( id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , mmyyyy varchar(6) NOT NULL CHECK (
                length(mmyyyy) = 6 AND
                left(mmyyyy,2)::integer BETWEEN 1 AND 12)
        );

INSERT INTO omg(mmyyyy) VALUES ('011901') ,('010001') ,('022016') ;
INSERT INTO omg(mmyyyy) VALUES ('131901') ;  -- should fail
INSERT INTO omg(mmyyyy) VALUES ('002016') ; -- should fail

SELECT id, mmyyyy FROM omg ;

        -- (3) use an int type and apply the check to the value/10000
CREATE TABLE wtf
        ( id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , mmyyyy INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (
                mmyyyy/10000 BETWEEN 1 AND 12)
        );

INSERT INTO wtf(mmyyyy) VALUES
 (11901) ,(10001) ,(22016)
        ;

INSERT INTO wtf(mmyyyy) VALUES (131901) ;  -- should fail
INSERT INTO wtf(mmyyyy) VALUES (2016) ; -- should fail

SELECT id, to_char(mmyyyy, '099999') AS mmyyyy
FROM wtf
        ;

        -- (extra) use an date/char/int type AS the baseclass for a domain(or type):
        -- (this can come in handy if the "type" is used in more than one place)
CREATE DOMAIN omgwtf AS
        INTEGER CHECK ( value/10000 BETWEEN 1 AND 12)
        ;

CREATE TABLE tralala
        ( id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
        , mmyyyy omgwtf NOT NULL
        );

INSERT INTO tralala(mmyyyy) VALUES
 (11901) ,(10001) ,(22016)
        ;

INSERT INTO tralala(mmyyyy) VALUES (131901) ;  -- should fail
INSERT INTO tralala(mmyyyy) VALUES (2016) ; -- should fail

SELECT id, to_char(mmyyyy, '099999') AS mmyyyy
FROM tralala
        ;
```

---

The output:

```
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 3
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "1901-13-01"
LINE 1: INSERT INTO mmyyyy(yyyymm01) VALUES ('1901-13-01') ;
                                             ^
HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
ERROR:  new row for relation "mmyyyy" violates check constraint "mmyyyy_yyyymm01_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, 2016-02-13).
 id |  this  
----+--------
  1 | 011901
  2 | 010001
  3 | 022016
(3 rows)

CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 3
ERROR:  new row for relation "omg" violates check constraint "omg_mmyyyy_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, 131901).
ERROR:  new row for relation "omg" violates check constraint "omg_mmyyyy_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (5, 002016).
 id | mmyyyy 
----+--------
  1 | 011901
  2 | 010001
  3 | 022016
(3 rows)

CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 3
ERROR:  new row for relation "wtf" violates check constraint "wtf_mmyyyy_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (4, 131901).
ERROR:  new row for relation "wtf" violates check constraint "wtf_mmyyyy_check"
DETAIL:  Failing row contains (5, 2016).
 id | mmyyyy  
----+---------
  1 |  011901
  2 |  010001
  3 |  022016
(3 rows)

CREATE DOMAIN
CREATE TABLE
INSERT 0 3
ERROR:  value for domain omgwtf violates check constraint "omgwtf_check"
ERROR:  value for domain omgwtf violates check constraint "omgwtf_check"
 id | mmyyyy  
----+---------
  1 |  011901
  2 |  010001
  3 |  022016
(3 rows)
```

Comment: Can't create a new table; the field should be part of an existing one. Can't afford to make a separate Java class just for this field. Also, (3) is not applicable, as the 0 in month should be preserved.

Comment: Your `numeric(6,0)` is (though a bad choice) very similar to my integer version. And Java is irrelevant, though it appears to allow strong typing